# How get state of application back once it turn off and again on?

Tags: android

I have created an application that sets two different alarms for morning and evening. Once we set the alarm and turn off the device, then after few minutes turn the device back on, the previously registered alarm will no longer invoke. I want the alarm to invoke even after device is turned off and on. What I can do?

I tried a lot with android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED and trying to set alarm once again but it is not working at all..

Thank you in advance.

Any help please..

Comment: Please show the relevant code in your app

Comment: Thank u for response neelsg... I got the solution for that.